# Why use an inductor as a fuse?

Tags: power-supply, inductor, mains, fuses

I opened a small "wall-wart" power supply that had failed, and discovered the culprit to be a low-value (100µH) standard (axial, green) inductor.

This inductor had a visible crack along it, as if it had overheated and released the "magic smoke". I confirmed it to be an inductor by cutting it open.

I am familiar with the practice of using a low-value *resistor* in place of a fuse, but not an inductor.

1. Why might an inductor have been used here?
2. Is there any obvious reason why a resistor (or an actual fuse) couldn't be substituted?
3. Why did it fail? It had been powering the device it was supplied with, for around six months, when it just failed for no apparent reason.
4. This product was an unbranded ethernet switch bought in the UK from Amazon. Is it really legal to sell mains-powered products without a "real" fuse in them?

Comment: "I confirmed it to be an inductor by cutting it open." I am curious to know how you distinguished an inductor from let's say wirewound resistor

Comment: @Maple Hold a magnet to the core material?

Comment: Most likely it's a part of the input line filter (e.g. PI filter). It's quite common to use those resistor-like inductors in low power offline regulators (e.g. wall-wart USB chargers). Since it's placed in series it may act as a fuse. You can check if both ends are connected to electrolytic capacitors to confirm that it's really a part of a PI filter.

Comment: @DKNguyen sure, if that's what OP has done. In any case, without knowing the location of the part in the schematics it is impossible to answer any of the OP questions

Comment: Holding a magnet to the core wouldn't work in all cases. Some inductors lack ferrous cores. In this case, I determined that the wire looked to be wound only in one direction. So even if it *were* intended to be a resistor, it was - de facto - an inductor.

Comment: The inductor was not connected to two capacitors. It was in series with the power, like a fuse, and the only method of power ingress.

Comment: I have a useless brick (that was *formerly* a modem) with similar internal 100uH cracked-open inductors. These failed as a result of a nearby lightning strike. The wiring into the modem served as an unfortunate antenna. These inductors were likely intended to suppress transient events...but they can only take just so much.